# python pandas dataframe add same row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Fruit        Quantity
orange       4
grape        2
apple        3
grape        2
orange       1
```

I want to sum up the quantity column based off of the same item name in the fruit column.
The desired result is :

```
Fruit      Quantity 
orange     5
apple      3
grape      4
```

Comment: `df.groupby("Fruit").sum()`

Answer (score 3):

The answers from @GevorgAtanesyan and @d.b work perfectly.
However to get a `DataFrame` instead of a `Serie` as output, this notation can be used :

```py
>>> df.groupby('Fruit')['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
    Fruit   Quantity
0   apple   3
1   grape   4
2   orange  5
```

EDIT :
As suggested by @EmiOB, it is even tidier to write it like this :

```py
>>> df.groupby('Fruit', as_index=False)['Quantity'].sum()
    Fruit   Quantity
0   apple   3
1   grape   4
2   orange  5
```

Comment: or add `as_index=False`  in the `df.groupby` bit, like so: `df.groupby('Fruit', as_index=False).sum()` Personally, I think it's a bit tidier

Answer (score 2):

Value counts is the best way

```
df.groupby('Fruit').sum()
```